# Convert a string into an int array

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering how would I convert a `string` to an `int` array.

I created a reader to read from a text file, which consists of two lines.

1. The first line is a random quote like "dogs are red"
2. The second line are numbers.

I am supposed to save each character from the quote into a `char` array, and then the second line, consisting of the numbers, is the order number of each `char`, and when printed out in that order, it will spell out a phrase.

I used the `.hasNextLine` method to first save the two lines into two string variables. Then, I converted the first line into the `char` array, and that part is ok but I do not know how to convert the second part into an `int` array.

I called the variable holding the second line "numbers" and it contains the string `"6 25 11 32 6 11 44......"`

How would I convert this into an `int` array?

Thanks so much

Comment: Wow, you described your intent in plain English :-). It helps when you paste the source code itself.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided code. That way we'd know where you're stuck.

Comment: Taking a leap of faith -- you have a string made of blank separated integers. Each integer is to be read as a "string". Try to separate these number substrings and send them to `Integer.valueOf`.

Comment: Your `String` of `ints` is delimited by spaces?

Comment: Hi, Sorry about that, let me post the code, and yes the numbers are seperated by spaces :). I have to run different files into my program, so everything varies a little bit.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something real simple like this:

```
String[] strArray = input.split(" ");
int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length]; 

for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
}
```

Also, you'd want to check for `NumberFormatException` using a `try..catch` block.

Answer (score 3):

If your numbers are delimited by spaces like it is described in your post, you can use `String.split()` to your advantage.

You can create a method like the following which will convert a `String` of integers to an `int[]`:

```
public static int[] stringArrayToIntArray(String intString) {
    String[] intStringSplit = intString.split(" "); //Split by spaces
    int[] result = new int[intStringSplit.length]; //Used to store our ints

    for (int i = 0; i < intStringSplit.length; i++) {
        //parse and store each value into int[] to be returned
        result[i] = Integer.parseInt(intStringSplit[i]); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which can be called like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String intString = "6 25 11 32 6 11 44"; //Original String

    int[] intArray = stringArrayToIntArray(intString); //Call our method

}
```

If you were to iterate through `intArray` and print each value with the following:

```
    for (int i : intArray) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

You'd get a result of:

> run: 
>       6 
>       25 
>       11 
>       32 
>       6 
>       11 
>       44 
>       BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Cheers!